# MS Word: Mailmerge hyperlinks with query get URL string with a MERGEFIELD

Tags: ms-word, fieldcodes, word-field

I'm trying to send an email merging one document (.docx) with a contacts database (via OleDB). Using MS Word 2007, it seems easy (it works for easy things: name, address, ...) but I can't find how fill an query-get URLD string with a merge field inside an hyperlink.

An hyperlink like: Click **here**

- where **here** is an hyperlink to
  http://domain.com/test.php?contact=contact@contactdomain.com

  - where contact@contactdomain.com is the
    address of the contact, a merge field.

I've tried the special/merge fields:

`{HYPERLINK "http://domain.com/test.php?contact={MERGEFIELD contactEmail}" \o "Here"}`

but it doesn't work, sometimes it merge only the first record and then send all the mails with the same address, I got this alternating the view with <kbd>ALT+F9</kbd>.

This [support doc](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/912679) doesn't work for me because I don't have the complete URL in my database for each contact, and I can't change the design of the table or add a view (it's from the CRM), I don't like to do it exporting the table and adding the field.

Any idea?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I think that MS forgot something in MSWord. In MS Publisher 2007 exists this functionality (called "Personalized hyperlinks") See at [here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/publisher/HP012330501033.aspx) to begin the mailmerge, then you can find an option to do that with an extra form (I didn't find in Word). I don't know if Word2010 has this option, but Publisher 2007 is OK for me.

Thx.